# How to discard null properties in SNS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a SQS queue consuming messages from a SNS topic which is owned by someone else. This topic sends JSON messages like the following :

```json
{
    "eventTime": 1603403123008,
    "state": {
        "propertyToFilter": "test",
        "version": 1
    }
}
```

I want to keep only messages where this `propertyToFilter` is **not null** (`propertyToFilter` is a nullable string property).

*Note : this is the body of the message. There are no message attributes on `propertyToFilter` so I'm trying to filter on the message body.*

Since I'm new to SNS filters, I went through the documentation and I though I could use something like :

```json
{
  "state": {
    "propertyToFilter": [
      {
        "anything-but": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However this is not accepted by SNS filters, as only string/numbers are valid, not `null` (*Value of anything-but must be an array or single string/number value*).

Maybe I'm missing something obvious here but I couldn't find an answer on the web.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your key problem the fact that `anything-but` won't accept `null`? Does your data actually says `{"propertyToFilter": null}`, or does it simply not include the field in the JSON?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Yes my key problem is `anything-but` not accepting null, but I am looking for any solution that would achieve discarding these events.
My data indeed includes fields like `{"propertyToFilter": null}`, the property is present but the value is null, otherwise I would have used the `exists` filter.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid that's not possible. You can set a filter for a property to equal null, but not vice versa.

There is a workaround if you know all possible first character values for the property value. In my case it was "value starts with any alphabetic character". So the filter policy, also very ugly, would be:

```
{
  "property": [
    {
      "prefix": "A"
    },
    ...
    {
      "prefix": "Z"
    },
    {
      "prefix": "a"
    },
    ...
    {
      "prefix": "z"
    }
}
```

Note: SNS filter policy compares values in a [case-sensitive manner](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/subscription-filter-policy-constraints.html):

> For string matching, the comparison is case-sensitive.

Keep in mind that there are [limitations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/dg/subscription-filter-policy-constraints.html) to this:

> ... the total combination of values must not exceed 150 ...

In the above case we have 52 combinations, so you have 98 extra for, say, including numbers or some special characters.